# iOS Swift ImagePickerController: Improving Edit Mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an ImagePickerController with allowsEditing = true. But I want to have more options in the edit screen, not just the resize mode. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to improve native image/video editing screen. If you need to have more options, you will need to create your own controller that will accept raw camera output and do its editing on that.

Comment: there is a lot of steps required, and it depends on your app's requirements. Do you problems with specific step?

Comment: I don't know where to start, let's suppose I want to add filters. I mean, should i build a custom view controller. And when the user press the takePhotoButton it will be redirect directly to the custom view controller? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you need to build new view controller that will apply filter the photo. When user presses take photo button, you will open image picker controller like you do now, with allowsEditing disabled. You will get user's photo through delegate and now you open your new custom VC and pass this photo to it. User will do editing and your new VC will return edited photo to wherever you need it to (probably same place where the take photo button is.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Lope you can make your own by gathering the camera input:

```
    import UIKit
    import AVFoundation
    import AssetsLibrary

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    var SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext = "SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext"
    var CapturingStillImageContext = "CapturingStillImageContext"

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
    public func fileOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

    }


    // MARK: property

    var sessionQueue: DispatchQueue!
    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    @objc var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?

    var deviceAuthorized: Bool  = false
    var backgroundRecordId: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    var sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized: Bool {
        get {
            return (self.session?.isRunning != nil && self.deviceAuthorized )
        }
    }

    var runtimeErrorHandlingObserver: AnyObject?
    var lockInterfaceRotation: Bool = false

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: AVCamPreviewView!
    @IBOutlet weak var snapButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

    var snappedimage = UIImage()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 let session: AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        self.session = session

        self.previewView.session = session

        self.checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus()

        let sessionQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "KehoeGames.whatever",attributes: [])

        self.sessionQueue = sessionQueue
        sessionQueue.async {
            self.backgroundRecordId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

            let videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice! = ViewController.deviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.video.rawValue, preferringPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back)
            var error: NSError? = nil


            var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
            do {
                videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                videoDeviceInput = nil
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }

            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription
                    , preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            if session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput!){
                session.addInput(videoDeviceInput!)
                self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                    let orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation =  AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)!

                    (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
                    (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

                }
            }
            //Audio

            let stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
                session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                self.stillImageOutput = stillImageOutput
            }
        }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.sessionQueue.async {

            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized", options: [.old , .new] , context: &SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext)
            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "stillImageOutput.capturingStillImage", options:[.old , .new], context: &CapturingStillImageContext)

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.subjectAreaDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: self.videoDeviceInput?.device)

            self.runtimeErrorHandlingObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureSessionRuntimeError, object: self.session, queue: nil) {
                (note: Notification?) in
                self.sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in
                    if let sess = self.session {
                        sess.startRunning()
                    }

                }
            }
            self.session?.startRunning()
        }
    }

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        self.sessionQueue.async {

            if let sess = self.session {
                sess.stopRunning()

                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: self.videoDeviceInput?.device)
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.runtimeErrorHandlingObserver!)

                self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "sessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorized", context: &SessionRunningAndDeviceAuthorizedContext)

                self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "stillImageOutput.capturingStillImage", context: &CapturingStillImageContext)
            }
        }
    }

 override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
        return !self.lockInterfaceRotation
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if context == &CapturingStillImageContext{
            let isCapturingStillImage: Bool = (change![NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey]! as AnyObject).boolValue
            if isCapturingStillImage {
                self.runStillImageCaptureAnimation()
            }

        }else {
            return super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        }
    }

@objc func subjectAreaDidChange(_ notification: Notification){
        let devicePoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.focusWithMode(AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode.continuousAutoFocus, exposureMode: AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode.continuousAutoExposure, point: devicePoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange: false)
    }

    // MARK:  Custom Function

    func focusWithMode(_ focusMode:AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode, exposureMode:AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode, point:CGPoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange:Bool){

        self.sessionQueue.async {
            let device: AVCaptureDevice! = self.videoDeviceInput!.device

            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode){
                    device.focusMode = focusMode
                    device.focusPointOfInterest = point
                }
                if device.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported && device.isExposureModeSupported(exposureMode){
                    device.exposurePointOfInterest = point
                    device.exposureMode = exposureMode
                }
                device.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
                device.unlockForConfiguration()

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

    class func setFlashMode(_ flashMode: AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode, device: AVCaptureDevice){

        if device.hasFlash && device.isFlashModeSupported(flashMode) {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                device.flashMode = flashMode
                device.unlockForConfiguration()

            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func runStillImageCaptureAnimation(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.previewView.layer.opacity = 0.0
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.previewView.layer.opacity = 1.0
            })
        }
    }

    class func deviceWithMediaType(_ mediaType: String, preferringPosition:AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {

        var devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: AVMediaType(rawValue: mediaType));

        if (devices.isEmpty) {
            print("This device has no camera. Probably the simulator.")
            return nil
        } else {
            var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = devices[0]

            for device in devices {
                if (device as AnyObject).position == preferringPosition {
                    captureDevice = device
                    break
                }
            }
            return captureDevice
        }
    }

 func checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus(){
        let mediaType:String = AVMediaType.video.rawValue;

        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType(rawValue: mediaType)) { (granted: Bool) in
            if granted {
                self.deviceAuthorized = true;
            } else {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(
                        title: "AVCam",
                        message: "AVCam does not have permission to access camera",
                        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in }
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                self.deviceAuthorized = false;
            }
        }
    }

    var snaptrue = false

    @IBAction func snapStillImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if snaptrue == false {
        snaptrue = true
        self.sessionQueue.async {
            // Update the orientation on the still image output video connection before capturing.

            let videoOrientation =  (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).connection?.videoOrientation

            self.stillImageOutput!.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.videoOrientation = videoOrientation!

            // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
            MeChoosePic.setFlashMode(AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.off, device: self.videoDeviceInput!.device)
            self.stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: self.stillImageOutput!.connection(with:AVMediaType.video)!, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, error: Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    let data:Data = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer!)!
                    //PNG
                    let imagesnap:UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
                    self.snappedimage = imagesnap
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.3, target: self, selector: #selector(self.move), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            })
        }
        }
    }

 @IBAction func changeCamera(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.cameraButton.isEnabled = false
        self.snapButton.isEnabled = false

        self.sessionQueue.async {

            let currentVideoDevice:AVCaptureDevice = self.videoDeviceInput!.device
            let currentPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = currentVideoDevice.position
            var preferredPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified

            switch currentPosition {
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.front:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.back:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
            case AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified:
                preferredPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back

            }

            guard let device:AVCaptureDevice? = MeChoosePic.deviceWithMediaType(AVMediaType.video.rawValue, preferringPosition: preferredPosition) else {
                print("there is no AVCapture Device")
                return
            }

            var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

            do {
                videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
            } catch _ as NSError {
                videoDeviceInput = nil
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }

            self.session!.beginConfiguration()

            self.session!.removeInput(self.videoDeviceInput!)

            if self.session!.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput!) {

                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object:currentVideoDevice)

                ViewController.setFlashMode(AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.auto, device: device!)

                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.subjectAreaDidChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVCaptureDeviceSubjectAreaDidChange, object: device)

                self.session!.addInput(videoDeviceInput!)
                self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

            } else {
                self.session!.addInput(self.videoDeviceInput!)
            }

            self.session!.commitConfiguration()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.snapButton.isEnabled = true
                self.cameraButton.isEnabled = true
            }

        }
    }

    @IBAction func focusAndExposeTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let devicePoint: CGPoint = (self.previewView.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view))

        self.focusWithMode(AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode.autoFocus, exposureMode: AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode.autoExpose, point: devicePoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange: true)
    }
```

And in AVCamPreviewView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class AVCamPreviewView: UIView {

    var session: AVCaptureSession? {
        get {
            return (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session
        }
        set (session) {
            (self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer).session = session
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
}
```

Do you also need the option of selecting picture already taking in the camera roll? - You just need to create a Collection View and fetch all the images to that. Just let me know!

Niall